# Obtaining a Unix Timestamp in Go Language (current time in seconds since epoch)

Tags: unix, timestamp, go

I have some code written in Go which I am trying to update to work with the latest weekly builds. (It was last built under r60). Everything is now working except for the following bit:

```
 if t, _, err := os.Time(); err == nil {
   port[5] = int32(t)
 }
```

Any advice on how to update this to work with the current Go implementation?

Answer (score 232, accepted):

```
import "time"
...
port[5] = time.Now().Unix()
```

Comment: go1.9.2 darwin/amd64 this consistently returns: 1969-12-31 19:00:00, which is roughly equivalent to: time.Unix(0, 0). This is without truncation.

Comment: That doesn't sound right @Breedly, or at least not any more: `func (t Time) Unix()` returns int64 ([doc](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time.Unix)).

Answer (score 54):

If you want it as `string` just convert it via `strconv`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    timestamp := strconv.FormatInt(time.Now().UTC().UnixNano(), 10)
    fmt.Println(timestamp) // prints: 1436773875771421417
}
```

Comment: What is the point of this? If someone wants to convert a number to a string, he can find how to do this. Or may be I should just add another answer: if you want to convert it to a bytearray, just do []byte(...)?

Comment: @SalvadorDali Actually this is exactly what I needed. Go ahead and add your answer to convert it to a byte array if you want I'm sure someone will come along eventually and need the code.

Comment: time.Now().UTC().UnixNano() can be replaced with time.Now().UnixNano() - the doc says that the result does not depend on the location associated with t.

Answer (score 18):

Another tip.  `time.Now().UnixNano()`[(godoc)](https://godoc.org/time#Time.UnixNano) will give you nanoseconds since the epoch.  It's not strictly Unix time, but it gives you sub second precision using the same epoch, which can be handy.

Edit: Changed to match current golang api

Comment: I know I'm resurrecting an old thread, but I'm wondering...  Python is clearly documenting the problems it has with getting a precise time on different platforms.  See http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html and search for "precision".  The point is: it's not because you have a float64 that all the decimals are significant.  How is Go's time implemented, how much can I trust this nanosecond precision?

Comment: You ask the operating system for the precision of whatever clock you're using.  golang seems not to properly expose this, so you'd need to know which OS clock it is using, and ask it directly through a syscall.  More on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14610459/how-precise-is-gos-time-really

Answer (score 1):

Building on the idea from another answer here, to get a human-readable interpretation, you can use:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    timestamp := time.Unix(time.Now().Unix(), 0)
    fmt.Printf("%v", timestamp) // prints: 2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC
}
```

Try it in [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/uLGsrJZBQLd).

Comment: The question does not ask for human-readable interpretation, but for the Unix timestamp, which is "the number of non-leap seconds which have passed since 00:00:00 UTC on Thursday, 1 January 1970, [and] is typically encoded as a signed integer" ([reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)).