# generate a random bool in go

Tags: go, random, boolean

What's the fastest way to generate a random bool in go ?

currently I'm doing like this :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

// random generator
var src = rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano())
var r = rand.New(src)

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        // generate a random boolean and print it 
        fmt.Printf("bool: %s\n", r.Intn(2) != 0)
    }
}
```

How can I improve this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I let a function randomly return either a true or a false in go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44719156/how-can-i-let-a-function-randomly-return-either-a-true-or-a-false-in-go/44719269#44719269).

Comment: Why src and r are global variables? Try to refrain using global variables. It becomes habit and then you continue with it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Examples of how to generate a random `bool` value can be found here (not necessarily the fastest solutions, as that wasn't a requirement there):

[How can I let a function randomly return either a true or a false in go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44719156/how-can-i-let-a-function-randomly-return-either-a-true-or-a-false-in-go/44719269#44719269)

The slowest part of such algorithms is always getting the random data (random information). For example a [`rand.Int31()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Int31) call returns 31 random bits, but if we only use it to "generate" a random `bool` value (which is 1 bit of information), we waste 30 bits (which could be 30 additional random `bool` values!).

Using [`rand.Source`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Source) is a good choice, as we don't need all the "code kung-fu" that [`rand.Rand`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Rand) does on the random data. We just need a source of random information.

`rand.Source` defines one method to obtain random information:

```
Int63() int64
```

This `Source.Int63()` method returns 63 random bits; to be fast(est), we should use all. Of course generating a single `bool` value requires only 1 of its bits, but we should store the remaining and use them when subsequent random `bool`s are asked from us.

This is how it can be done:

```
type boolgen struct {
    src       rand.Source
    cache     int64
    remaining int
}

func (b *boolgen) Bool() bool {
    if b.remaining == 0 {
        b.cache, b.remaining = b.src.Int63(), 63
    }

    result := b.cache&0x01 == 1
    b.cache >>= 1
    b.remaining--

    return result
}
```

Creating such a `boolgen` is like this:

```
func New() *boolgen {
    return &boolgen{src: rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano())}
}
```

Example usage:

```
r := New()
for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
    if i%10 == 0 {
        fmt.Println()
    }
    fmt.Print(r.Bool(), " ")
}
```

Example output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/oucs3zxcr_)):

```
false false true true false false false false false false 
false false false true false false true false true true 
false false true false true false false true true true 
false false false false false false false true true false 
true true true true false false false false true false 
true true true false true true true true true true 
true true false true true false false true false true 
true true false false false true true true true false 
true false false true true true true false false true 
true false false false false false false false true false
```

**Some notes:**

The `Source` returned by [`rand.NewSource()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#NewSource) is not safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines, so our `boolgen` is also not safe for concurrent use. On one hand this is *good*, as it will be faster (as no synchronization takes place) than using the default source of the `rand` package which is safe in this manner (which is by the way unexported, so can only be "reached" indirectly through functions of the `rand` package).

If you need to use this from multiple goroutines, *fastest* (as in spirit of the question) would be for all goroutines to create their own `boolgen`, so no synchronization is needed.

If `boolgen` itself must be made safe for concurrent use, simply its `Bool()` method should be protected with a [`sync.Mutex`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex).

Answer (score 15):

I am just a rookie, but this makes more sense to me than other solutions provided:

```
package randbool

import (
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

/*
RandBool
    This function returns a random boolean value based on the current time
*/
func RandBool() bool {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    return rand.Intn(2) == 1
}
```

I am not too familiar with go though, so please forgive my formating.

Comment: nice solution tough you could always just return rand.Intn(2) == 1 without the else :D

Comment: @Kashkashio thanks for the edit.  I end up making that mistake more than I intend to.

Comment: `rand.Intn(2)` returns always `1`, because the numbers generated by the `Intn()` function are greater than `0` and do not include (are less than) the parameter passed to the function. So, `return rand.Intn(3) == 1` should be the correct return.

Comment: ^^ That's incorrect `rand.Intn(2)` alternates between 0 and 1.  This is easily tested.  If you use `rand.Intn(3)` expect to get a heavily weighted bool, true ~33% of the time and false ~66% of the time.

Answer (score 4):

I did a speed comparison of different methods using `math/rand` package from stdlib and [`github.com/MichaelTJones/pcg`](https://github.com/MichaelTJones/pcg), another pseudorandom number generator in go

Here is the code I used for timing the different variants:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "testing"

    "github.com/MichaelTJones/pcg"
)

func BenchmarkBool(b *testing.B) {

    pcg32 := pcg.NewPCG32()

    ff := []func() bool{
        func() bool { return rand.Intn(2) == 0 },          // 1
        func() bool { return rand.Int31n(2) == 0 },        // 2
        func() bool { return rand.Int63n(2) == 0 },        // 3
        func() bool { return rand.Float32() < .5 },        // 4
        func() bool { return rand.Float64() < .5 },        // 5
        func() bool { return rand.Int31()&(1<<30) == 0 },  // 6
        func() bool { return rand.Uint32()&(1<<31) == 0 }, // 7
        func() bool { return rand.Int63()&(1<<62) == 0 },  // 8
        func() bool { return rand.Uint64()&(1<<63) == 0 }, // 9
        func() bool { return pcg32.Random()&0x01 == 0 },   // 10
    }
    for i, f := range ff {
        b.Run(fmt.Sprintf("method%v", i+1), func(b *testing.B) {
            for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
                _ = f()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

On my machine, the output of this program is

```
BenchmarkBool/method1-4             50000000            36.8 ns/op
BenchmarkBool/method2-4             50000000            34.7 ns/op
BenchmarkBool/method3-4             50000000            31.5 ns/op
BenchmarkBool/method4-4             50000000            33.3 ns/op
BenchmarkBool/method5-4             50000000            30.1 ns/op
BenchmarkBool/method6-4             50000000            29.4 ns/op
BenchmarkBool/method7-4             50000000            31.0 ns/op
BenchmarkBool/method8-4             50000000            28.7 ns/op
BenchmarkBool/method9-4             50000000            29.5 ns/op
BenchmarkBool/method10-4            300000000            4.86 ns/op
```

*i.e.* method number 10 is fastest, and number 1 is slowest.

Comment: @felix I have to say that I liked my answer better before the edit, when it compared only methods available via the standard library.  If adding external packages, why only the obscure `github.com/MichaelTJones/pcg` and no others?

Comment: Sorry to hear that ! I included the `pcg` package because it's the solution that will likely be used in go2 ( see [github.com/golang/go/issues/21835](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/21835) for details ), and the solution I ended up using in my project. Feel free to rollback my changes ( if you can't just let me know, I'll do it for you)

Comment: @felix Ah, thanks!  If `pcg` is on its way into the standard library, its inclusion here looks much less random.

Answer (score -1):

hi i use this approach and it's working well

random_bool.go

```
import (
      "math/rand"
      "time"
)

const (
    Agree = 1
    Disagree = 0
)

func AreYouAgree() bool {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    ran := rand.Intn(Agree + 1)
    if ran == Agree {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

thanks for reading answer. ;)