# Date.now() equivalent in Go

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, time, go

In JavaScript, I can assign:

`var now = Date.now();`

Then use `now` to calculate as a number variable

`time.Time` type in Go doesn't seem to meet this demand. What is the Go equivalent of JavaScript's `Date.now()` ?

Comment: Possibly [Obtaining a Unix Timestamp in Go Language (current time in seconds since epoch)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539108/obtaining-a-unix-timestamp-in-go-language-current-time-in-seconds-since-epoch)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Date.now()` returns milliseconds since epoch UTC

> The now() method returns the milliseconds elapsed since 1 January 1970
> 00:00:00 UTC up until now as a Number.

To get that in Go, you can use:

```
time.Now().UTC().UnixNano() / 1e6
```

or since Go version `1.17`

```
time.Now().UTC().UnixMilli()
```

Comment: What does the `/ 1e6` part do?

Comment: `UnixNano()` returns Nanoseconds.  To get from Nano to Milli, you divide by 1000000.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Now](https://golang.org/src/time/time.go?s=22856:22871#L771) function from "time" package as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(time.Now())
    fmt.Println(time.Now().Date())
}
```

Sample output:

```
2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC
2009 November 10
```

Here is function explanation from documentation:

```
func Now() Time
```

**Now returns the current local time.**

```
func (t Time) Date() (year int, month Month, day int)
```

**Date returns the year, month, and day in which t occurs.**

Watch it in [**Live Demo**](https://play.golang.org/p/GX4KvDA7UH).

Answer (score 3):

Date.Now() returns the current UTC date and time in epoch(unix) format. The equivalent in go would be:

`time.Now().Unix()`

`time.Now()` returns the current time. Calling `Unix()` converts the time to epoch or unix time, which is `the number of seconds elapsed since January 1, 1970 UTC`

[Full GoDocs for Time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Unix)

Answer (score 1):

In go you can use method `time.Now().Date()`

Answer (score 0):

In go you can use these methods

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)
func main() {

    currentTime := time.Now()
    
    fmt.Println(currentTime.Date())  //

    fmt.Println("Current Time in String: ", currentTime.String())

    fmt.Println("MM-DD-YYYY : ", currentTime.Format("01-02-2006"))

    fmt.Println("YYYY-MM-DD : ", currentTime.Format("2006-01-02"))

    fmt.Println("YYYY.MM.DD : ", currentTime.Format("2006.01.02 15:04:05"))

    fmt.Println("YYYY#MM#DD {Special Character} : ", currentTime.Format("2006#01#02"))

    fmt.Println("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss : ", currentTime.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"))

    fmt.Println("Time with MicroSeconds: ", currentTime.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05.000000"))

    fmt.Println("Time with NanoSeconds: ", currentTime.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05.000000000"))

    fmt.Println("ShortNum Month : ", currentTime.Format("2006-1-02"))

    fmt.Println("LongMonth : ", currentTime.Format("2006-January-02"))

    fmt.Println("ShortMonth : ", currentTime.Format("2006-Jan-02"))

    fmt.Println("ShortYear : ", currentTime.Format("06-Jan-02"))

    fmt.Println("LongWeekDay : ", currentTime.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05 Monday"))

    fmt.Println("ShortWeek Day : ", currentTime.Format("2006-01-02 Mon"))

    fmt.Println("ShortDay : ", currentTime.Format("Mon 2006-01-2"))

    fmt.Println("Short Hour Minute Second: ", currentTime.Format("2006-01-02 3:4:5"))

    fmt.Println("Short Hour Minute Second: ", currentTime.Format("2006-01-02 3:4:5 PM"))

    fmt.Println("Short Hour Minute Second: ", currentTime.Format("2006-01-02 3:4:5 pm"))

//  2021 February 10
//  Current Time in String:  2021-02-10 11:47:30.5807222 +0530 +0530 m=+0.001994001
//  MM-DD-YYYY :  02-10-2021
//  YYYY-MM-DD :  2021-02-10
//  YYYY.MM.DD :  2021.02.10 11:47:30
//  YYYY#MM#DD {Special Character} :  2021#02#10
//  YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss :  2021-02-10 11:47:30
//  Time with MicroSeconds:  2021-02-10 11:47:30.580722
//  Time with NanoSeconds:  2021-02-10 11:47:30.580722200
//  ShortNum Month :  2021-2-10
//LongMonth :  2021-February-10
//ShortMonth :  2021-Feb-10
//ShortYear :  21-Feb-10
//LongWeekDay :  2021-02-10 11:47:30 Wednesday
//  ShortWeek Day :  2021-02-10 Wed
//ShortDay :  Wed 2021-02-10
//  Short Hour Minute Second:  2021-02-10 11:47:30
//  Short Hour Minute Second:  2021-02-10 11:47:30 AM
//  Short Hour Minute Second:  2021-02-10 11:47:30 am

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Go**

```golang
time.Now().UTC().UnixMilli()
```

See reference: https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time.UnixMilli

> Note: I am using `go 1.20` when I discovered this.

**Javascript**

```
Date.now()
```

Both will have the same result: `1677469641253`