# How i can to convert RFC3339 to UNIX in golang

Tags: go

I want to show some RFC3339 time as seconds. I found how to parse times string, but it not that

```
t, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2012-11-01T22:08:41+00:00")
```

Comment: If the time is parsed correctly, what is the problem you're having?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Obtaining a Unix Timestamp in Go Language (current time in seconds since epoch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539108/obtaining-a-unix-timestamp-in-go-language-current-time-in-seconds-since-epoch)

Comment: @Flimzy: It has to be an exact duplicate. It has to be correct. `int32(time.Now().Unix())` is a bug since `Unix()` returns `int64`. See [Year 2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2012-11-01T22:08:41+00:00")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(t)
    // Unix returns t as a Unix time,
    // the number of seconds elapsed since January 1, 1970 UTC.
    fmt.Println(t.Unix())
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/LG6G4lMIWt

Output:

```
2012-11-01 22:08:41 +0000 UTC
1351807721
```