# Storing timestamp in variable

Tags: go

Is it possible to store the timestamp in a variable like a log function when printing out? Because time.Now is giving too much detail. I did try something like:

```
    //dt := time.Now()
    //times := dt.String()
    x := []string{cokeAmountStr, spriteAmountStr, fantaAmountStr, mirindaAmountStr, mineralWaterAmountStr, priceStr, mReceivedStr, mReturnStr}
    transaction = (strings.Join(x, ","))
    var data string = log.Println(transaction)
}
```

But it won't work

Comment: [time.Time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time) has a number of methods on it for different ways to format it into a string or an integer. Read through the docs and see which one works for you.

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean? What problem did you encounter?

Comment: I also don't understand what you mean at all. `dt := time.Now()` *does* store a timestamp in a variable. What else do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi and welcome to StackOverflow.

to get Unix time you can use [`time.Unix()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Unix):

```
var timestamp int64
timestamp = time.Now().Unix()
```

also, you can get [`formatted`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format) string from time

```
var formatted string
t := time.now()
layout := "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"
t.Format(layout)
```

list of layout constats : https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants

Comment: If this is the answer to the question, then the question is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9539108/13860), and probably a dozen others.

Comment: @Flimzy Yes, I think this is the answer to this question, cause he said `time.Now is giving too much detail`, also I will add `format` to my answer.

Comment: `time.Format` is also well covered in other Q&As.  Whatever the answer, I'm about 99.99% positive that this question is a duplicate. But since the question is completely unclear, it's hard to say what it's a duplicate of.  It's usually best to get the OP to clarify the question, rather than providing random answers that may or may not be on target.

Comment: @Flimzy Yep, you are right. so should I delete my answer?

Comment: @JackNicolus_XI: That's a unix timestamp and is a standard way to represent time. If this doesn't work for you, clarify your question, we don't know what you're looking for.

Comment: What I would like to have is a simple date and time for the time stamp. But time.Now() is too much detailed.

Comment: Now I'm trying to use .Format("2017.09.07 17:06:06") and I'm having 15097.09.07 97:20:20 as a result.

Comment: Use the [Format](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format) method to pass in a custom format, or use one of the one of the [predefined-ones](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants). It's all in the docs.

Comment: This is not how the format is specified, it needs to match the reference date shown in the docs. In your case: `2006.01.02 15:04:05`.